# Store In App Purchase purchased items with Firebase : security issue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I was wondering if it worths considering to save all users IAP purchased products ID into a Firebase private database (only accessible with a rule auth = user_uid ) ?

What are security threats ? Is Firebase secure enough to handle such data ?

My need is to access locally (if no internet connection available) users purchased items. For now on IOS, I'm using a receipt validation : https://gist.github.com/baileysh9/4386ea92b047d97c7285#file-parsing_productids-swift but the code is completely out dated since Swift 3 and do not know how to update it ... so I'm looking for other methods.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I wish this would get an answer.  I am trying to find a secure way to store an IAP and allow it to be available to all devices.  KeyChain is secure enough I think, but then when the user downloads the app onto a new device they would need to go through the process of restoring the purchase to get in on that device too.  I have implemented receipt verification, and would really like to find a solution for this.

Comment: Hi Scooter ! After all I found a solution to update the receipt validation code for Swift 3 so I do not use Firebase to store my IAP product ID. However, at the time, I sent a request to Firebase in order to get an answer. The answer was that Firebase was secured enough to store the data if good security rules are written. Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Have rolled my own solution using KeyChain and receipt refresh requests with server side verification that I think is pretty secure.  I won't be using Firebase for this I think.

Comment: @GrayFox did they give any insight to how to write the security rules!?

Comment: Can anyone share their code in how you solved your issue?!

Comment: For security rules : I guess using private access is enough. Ex: "$user_id === auth.uid" 
Then, which code about which issue ?